# Remove and Return First Item of List

Tags: c#, list

I was wondering if there was a build in method to remove and return the first item of a list with one method/command.

I used this, which was not pretty

```
Item currentItem = items.First();
items.RemoveAt(0);
```

So I could wrote an extension-method:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T RemoveAndReturnFirst<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        T currentFirst = list.First();
        list.RemoveAt(0);
        return currentFirst;
    }
 }

//Example code
Item currentItem = items.RemoveAndReturnFirst();
```

Is this the best possibility or is there any built-in method?

The list is returned from a nHibernate-Query and therefore it should remain a `List<T>`.

Comment: "Not pretty" and "best possibility" make this rather opinion-based. .NET is not PHP where a function is introduced for every combination of two statements. What is your actual question? Whether this particular method is built into `List<T>` or available as an extension method? Then no.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most suitable collection for this operation is [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
queue.Enqueue(10); //add first
queue.Enqueue(20); //add to the end

var first = queue.Dequeue(); //removes first and returns it (10)
```

Queue makes `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` operations very fast. But, if you need to search inside queue, or get item by index - it's bad choice. Compare, how many different types of operations do you have and according to this choose the most suitable collection - queue, stack, list or simple array.

Also you can create a `Queue` from a `List`:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var queue = new Queue<int>(list);
```

Comment: _If_ the sole requirement is _"I want a generic collection to store and retrieve objects FIFO"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, of couse, I added some explanations

Comment: @CodeCaster If you want a list to behave like, 'remove the first item and return it', then it becomes a queue what you want.

Comment: @mecek absolutely not. It is adding functionality to a list that it doesn't have out of the box. If it is the _only_ requirement, then a `Queue<T>` may be a better choice. If however OP still wants to be able to index into the collection or be able to remove items from other indices than the first, `List<T>` is still a better fit.

Answer (score 8):

There is no built-in method. Your code looks fine to me.

One small thing, I would use the indexer, not the `First` extension method:

```
T currentFirst = list[0];
```

And check your list if there is a `Count > 0`.

```
public static T RemoveAndReturnFirst<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
    {
        // Instead of returning the default,
        // an exception might be more compliant to the method signature.

        return default(T);
    }

    T currentFirst = list[0];
    list.RemoveAt(0);
    return currentFirst;
}
```

If you have to worry about concurrency, I would advice to use another collection type, since this one isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Your code looks like RemoveAndReturnFirstOrDefault method.

Comment: Indeed, instead of `default(T)` and exception would be a possibility too, maybe even better :).